# Getting GPS from user's phone to verify they are in the United States

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gps

I'm making an app and I want to restrict it to the United States via GPS on the users phone.  (I know permission will have to added to get access to their GPS) Geolocking on Google Play doesn't really do anything because of the huge access to VPNs to bypass that.

How would I go about to getting their location via their GPS and making sure they are ACTUALLY in the United States.

This game is being coded within Unity in C# language.  I don't expect a full on copy-pasta code but more of a direction to be pointed towards weather its documentations or other examples that you have seen.  Just a nice little nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you'll probably get a lot of complaints and bad reviews for requesting the location permissions, GPS is really easy to spoof, so I'm not sure you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

GPS is a Polar Coordinate System. Just find the min/max ranges you want your users to be restricted to and treat it like a bounding box (but, obviously, with polar coordinates).

That said, given that spoofing a GPS is even easier than spoofing a Geo-IP, I have to ask, why is this such a big deal for you?

Answer (score 0):

Spoofing GPS is easy, starting with a long list of Fake GPS apps and all the way to actually transmitting RF GPS signals using a software-defined radio and GitHub's gps-sdr-sim. When spoofing is done right, it is not trivial to know you are being spoofed. There are several software solutions out there trying to solve this problem - a quick Google search will give you some options.